# What is the Prof. method to layout the install file in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04

```
user@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ tree mongodb-linux-i686-2.0.0
mongodb-linux-i686-2.0.0
|-- bin
|   |-- bsondump
|   |-- mongo
|   |-- mongod
|   |-- mongodump
|   |-- mongoexport
|   |-- mongofiles
|   |-- mongoimport
|   |-- mongorestore
|   |-- mongos
|   |-- mongosniff
|   |-- mongostat
|   `-- mongotop
|-- GNU-AGPL-3.0
|-- README
`-- THIRD-PARTY-NOTICES
```

I need to install MongoDB and above is the expanded folder structure of the MongoDB.

Question:

Where should I store the folder `mongodb-linux-i686-2.0.0`?
Or Should I copy all files under `mongodb-linux-i686-2.0.0/bin` to `/user/bin/`?

I just want to do it in a professional way since I will install more and more application on my machine.

Comment: Want to know the reason for down-vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite common to install third-party software in `/usr/local` or (less common) in `/opt` (for example, both Mathematica and Matlab install their binaries in `/usr/local`.

`/usr/local` is, according to the [FHS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard), the "tertiary hierarchy for local data, specific to this host". Installing your software here ensures that its files will not be overwritten by system updates. So, you should copy `mongodb-linux-i686-2.0.0` in `/usr/local` and you should add `/usr/local/mongodb-linux-i686-2.0.0/bin` to the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Refer to [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-my-path) for how to add the path.